# Spring Websocket dynamic subscribption

Tags: spring-security, spring-websocket

Is it possible to do a dynamic subscription with spring WebSocket?

We have a multi-tenancy application and the need is to send messages to a group of users within the tenant. I am currently achieving his with a user-specific queue, but this is not effective as we are adding the same message to all the user's queues. The problem with using a tenant-specific topic is from the client any one case subscribe to the same topic once the topic name is known.

Any ideas or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Topic and subscribe it from every user (frontend).
Then you send the Messages for a group of Users to this Topic.
So every subscribed user get Updates broadcasted.

Perhaps this Tutorial would help.
https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/spring/spring-boot-websocket-stomp-tutorial/

To make it more secure, you can add the SessionIDs to virtual groups, so its safe only specific users are allowed to subscribe the Topic.